# The 'Accept' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method - TwitchAPI

Tags: vb.net, winforms, exception, httpwebrequest

My problem, as you can see in the title, is I get an exception when adding the header. What I'm trying to do is send an authorization request to the public [TwitchAPI](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API). Here's the request that I'm trying to translate:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json' 
-H 'Authorization: OAuth <access_token>' \ 
-X GET https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channel
```

It's when I add the Accept header where this exception pops up in my face (title). I'm not sure if I've translated this correctly but this is the code I have right now:

```
Dim wr = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channel"), HttpWebRequest)
wr.Method = "GET"
wr.Headers.Add("Authorization: OAuth <oauth_token>")
wr.Headers.Add("Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json")
Return CType(wr.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

where oauth_token is my access token, anyone who could solve this for me? Really worked my ass off trying to figure out such a simple thing, thanks!

- Oh and also, when I remove the header (which I actually think is unnecessary) it says im unauthorized, using the correct access token.

Answer (score 7):

The `HttpWebRequest` class has a specific [`Accept`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.accept(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) property for setting the 'Accept' header

```
Dim wr = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channel"), HttpWebRequest)
wr.Method = "GET"
wr.Headers.Add("Authorization: OAuth <oauth_token>")
wr.Accept = "application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json"
Return CType(wr.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

Comment: I guess it works, keep getting the unauthorized exception even when using the right token tho.

Comment: Sounds like that's another question to ask

Comment: Wow -- it pays to explore the entire object instead of assuming you can add headers to a collection of headers...  It's these little things that explode development time unpredictably!  Thanks for the straight forward answer!